# XQuery a SQL Server NVARCHAR column

Tags: xml, t-sql, nvarchar, xquery-sql

I have a table with a `nvarchar` column which stores XML. I'm trying to find all rows which has a specific node empty

Here is the structure of the table `JOB`:

```
ID           NVARCAHR(64)
NAME         NVARCAHR(128) 
ExtraInfo    NVARCAHR(MAX)
```

Here is  a sample of the content of the column `ExtraInfo`, I'm looking for:

```
<ModifyMetadata>
    <hostName t="ws">host2</hostName>
    <Name t="ws">myname</Name>
    <modifiedFields t="lt">
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">foo</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s/>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">bar</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s/>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        </modifiedFields>
</ModifyMetadata>
```

With this sample basically I'm looking for all rows with the node `ModifyMetadata` and where the nodes `ExtraInfoAdditionalField\Values` are empty (this is my understanding of what `<s/>` means).

First I tried with a simple `LIKE` in with this query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [JOB]
WHERE ExtraInfo LIKE '%\>\<\/s\>%' ESCAPE '\'
```

But this query also returns rows where the nodes `ExtraInfoAdditionalField\Values` have some content.

The XQuery way: I switched to another method where I'm trying to `CAST` the column to XML and then return only the row where the nodes `ExtraInfoAdditionalField\Values` are empty.

But then I'm getting confused about the methodolgy to query this column with XQuery or any other available methodology.

I have tried to `CAST` directly in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT CAST(ExtraInfo AS XML)
FROM [JOB]
WHERE ExtraInfo.value('XQUERYHERE') IS NULL
```

But SQL Server doesn't know what `ExtraInfo. value` is.

I tried to `CAST` it in a variable:

```
DECLARE @ExtraInfo XML
SET @ExtraInfo = CAST([MYDB].[dbo].[JOB].ExtraInfo AS XML)

SELECT ExtraInfo 
FROM [JOB]
WHERE @ExtraInfo.value('XQUERYHERE') IS NULL
```

But SQL doesn't understand what is `[MYDB].[dbo].[JOB].ExtraInfo`

I have tried to `CAST` directly in the `SELECT` and rename it:

```
SELECT CAST(ExtraInfo AS XML) as myinfo
FROM [JOB]
WHERE myinfo.value('XQUERYHERE') IS NULL
```

But T-SQL doesn't know what `myinfo` is.

So I'm clearly lacking of understanding in what way It possible to XML query a column which is stored in `NVARCHAR` format

I hope this I this is clear enough, thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 1):

What you didn't try is the obvious solution - which is to cast the `ExtraInfo` column to `xml` inside the `where` clause:

```
SELECT Id, [Name], ExtraInfo 
FROM [JOB]
WHERE CAST(ExtraInfo as xml).value('XQUERYHERE') IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes rather late, so I don't know if you still need this...

First of all: It is a bad idea to store XML as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. If you can change this, you should use the native XML data-type.

However, it is important to know, that XML does not know a `NULL` (uhm, there is `xsi:nil`, but that's something else), but it knows **missing elements** (which are *translated* to `NULL` in T-SQL) and **empty elements**, which you can query using `empty(SomeXPathHere)` or - vice versa - `not(empty(SomeXPathHere))`.

You did not state your expected output, so I'll provide several approaches and hope the one you need is included:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(64), [NAME] NVARCHAR(128), ExtraInfo NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 ('id1','both without',
 N'<ModifyMetadata>
    <hostName t="ws">host2</hostName>
    <Name t="ws">myname</Name>
    <modifiedFields t="lt">
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">foo</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s/>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">bar</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s/>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        </modifiedFields>
</ModifyMetadata>')
,('id2','one with and one without content',
 N'<ModifyMetadata>
    <hostName t="ws">host2</hostName>
    <Name t="ws">myname</Name>
    <modifiedFields t="lt">
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">foo</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s>SomeValueHere</s>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">bar</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s/> <!-- No value here -->
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        </modifiedFields>
</ModifyMetadata>')
,('id2','both with content',
 N'<ModifyMetadata>
    <hostName t="ws">host2</hostName>
    <Name t="ws">myname</Name>
    <modifiedFields t="lt">
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">foo</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s>SomeValueHere</s>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        <ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
            <FieldName t="ws">bar</FieldName>
            <Values t="lws">
                <s>And here too</s>
            </Values>
            <FieldType t="ws">String</FieldType>
        </ExtraInfoAdditionalField>
        </modifiedFields>
</ModifyMetadata>');
```

--this returns all rows where at least on `<s>` is empty

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.[NAME]
      ,Casted
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.ExtraInfo AS XML)) A(Casted)
WHERE Casted.exist('/ModifyMetadata/modifiedFields/ExtraInfoAdditionalField[empty(Values/s/text())]')=1
```

--this returns a list of all fields (each field as separate row) if `<s>` is empty

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.[NAME]
      ,B.dt.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') FieldWithNonEmpty_s
      ,B.dt.query('.') TheNode
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.ExtraInfo AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/ModifyMetadata/modifiedFields/ExtraInfoAdditionalField[empty(Values/s/text())]/FieldName') B(dt)
```

--this returns a list of all fields (each field as separate row) and will carry a NULL if `<s>` is empty

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.[NAME]
      ,B.dt.value('(FieldName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') FieldWithNonEmpty_s
      ,B.dt.value('(Values/s/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') TheTextInS
      ,B.dt.query('.') TheNode
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.ExtraInfo AS XML)) A(Casted)
OUTER APPLY Casted.nodes('/ModifyMetadata/modifiedFields/ExtraInfoAdditionalField[Values/s/text()]') B(dt);
```